# Bitmap - compare contact picture with picture on sd card

Tags: android, bitmap, android-contacts

I want to check, if the current user picture of a contact is the same as the one on the sd card...

I set the user picture like following:

```
byte[] photo = ImageFunctions.convertImageToByteArray(bitmap);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
....
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo);
...
```

And I read the image like following:

```
InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
    contentResolver,
    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, mId), 
    fullsize);

if (inputStream != null)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

And my convert function is following:

```
public static byte[] convertImageToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream streamy = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, streamy);
    return streamy.toByteArray();
}
```

And I use a md5 hash on the byte array of the bitmap to find changes... Actually, the images are not exactly the same.

What can I do, so that I compare the hash codes? It seems, like compression or whatever is not exactly the same, so the md5 hash check fails...

Comment: Well, the safest way would be to compare the uncompressed bytes of each.  But if either version was changed at all-  for example cropping or downsampling of the version used for the contact picture- you won't ever get that to work, you'd have to move on to complex computer vision techniques.

Comment: No one will change the bitmap on the sd card... Only the contacts picture can be changed manually, that's why I can't save the md5 hash to a database... I always have to check the actual contact photo...

Comment: And even if I change my convert function and use something like `bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);`, even then I don't get the same bitmap from the Contact back...